# HashSet contains copy of object

Tags: java, data-structures, set, hashset, breadth-first-search

I have an object of class Point with members x and y. I want to check if a Point object is in my 'visited' HashSet, but when I check, I create a new object with the current values of x and y. Even if a point with those values is in the set, it returns false, I'm guessing since it's not the exact same object. How can I check if the set contains a point with just the same x and y?

Comment: You should write an equals method in your Point object.
 Then use that method for comparison

Answer (score 2):

Override the **equals()** method to actually check the values of your **x** and **y** inside **Point**

Comment: hashCode() too, and it should be consistent with equals().

Comment: @CyrilleKa of course (Netbeans does it auto-magically for me usually :P)